# sqlite query works with addition but not division

Tags: sql, sqlite

Why does this SQLite statement work with addition but not division ? I am trying to divide the sum of two queries by a third : (Q1 + Q2) / Q3.

Here, Q1 and Q2 have been combined into a single query, which I am trying to divide by the third query.

Here is the code for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE subset_all(
  "SegmentID" TEXT,
  "RatingDateTime" TEXT,
  "Rating" TEXT,
  "value" TEXT
);
```

Here is the code that works when I use addition. I found out it works by trying to debug the division case :

```
select(
(select sum(LM)
FROM(
SELECT sum(value) LM
FROM (SELECT segmentid, rating, RatingDateTime, value
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY segmentid ORDER BY RatingDateTime DESC) AS rn
      FROM subset_all
      WHERE RatingDateTime < date('2014-10-20'))
WHERE rating >= 7 AND rn = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(value) LM
FROM (SELECT segmentid, rating, RatingDateTime, value
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY segmentid ORDER BY RatingDateTime DESC) AS rn
      FROM subset_all
      WHERE RatingDateTime < date('2014-10-20'))
WHERE rating >= 8 AND rn = 1
))
+
(select sum(LM) from (
SELECT sum(value) LM
FROM (SELECT segmentid, RatingDateTime, value
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY segmentid ORDER BY RatingDateTime DESC) AS rn
      FROM subset_all
      WHERE RatingDateTime < date('2014-10-20'))
WHERE rn = 1 
)
)
);
```

This is the code I want to execute, it does not work when I use division!

```
select(
    (select sum(LM)
     FROM(
        SELECT sum(value) LM
        FROM (
            SELECT segmentid, rating, RatingDateTime, value
               , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY segmentid ORDER BY RatingDateTime DESC) AS rn
            FROM subset_all
            WHERE RatingDateTime < date('2014-10-20')
        )
        WHERE rating >= 7 AND rn = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sum(value) LM
        FROM (
            SELECT segmentid, rating, RatingDateTime, value
               , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY segmentid ORDER BY RatingDateTime DESC) AS rn
            FROM subset_all
            WHERE RatingDateTime < date('2014-10-20')
        )
        WHERE rating >= 8 AND rn = 1
    )
    )
    /
    (select sum(LM) 
     from (
        SELECT sum(value) LM
        FROM (
            SELECT segmentid, RatingDateTime, value
                   , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY segmentid ORDER BY RatingDateTime DESC) AS rn
            FROM subset_all
            WHERE RatingDateTime < date('2014-10-20')
        )
        WHERE rn = 1 
    )
    )
);
```

Here is the error I get when running the non working code :

```
Error: near "(": syntax error
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your query runs fine. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Can't reproduce with mock data and using CTE to avoid repeating subquery. See [DB fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hdP7JqJWgozHqUsiHsUb11/0) (click *Run*).

Comment: Division by zero?

Comment: @parfait
I debugged with your code, and it turned out that my code did not work because the division sign was on a new line. When I put all of this on one line it worked :  ) / (

Comment: That cannot be the issue. What IDE are you using? Are your running through code? SQLite's command line? My DB fiddle demo has the division operator on its own line.

Comment: command line, seriously, the only thing I changed was that. However, when addition was on its own line, it worked in command line, when division was on its own line, it did not work.